# Why this index value changes?

Tags: c++

I'm sorry if this is not MCV code, but this error is driving me so mad that I have **no idea** of what this is about at all, I

I have this function:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "BeladyAlgorithm.hpp"

#define VERBOSE 0

float computeOptimalCHR(const std::vector<cv::Mat1f> setupQueries, const std::vector<cv::Mat1f> queries, size_t cacheSize, float threshold){
    std::vector<cv::Mat1f> cache(cacheSize, cv::Mat1f());
    //nextUse[i] = k it means that that the i-th cached element will be used at time k
    std::vector<int> nextUse(cacheSize, -1);
    std::vector<int> temp(cacheSize, 0);
    int nQueries = queries.size(), cacheHits=0, cacheHitFound, freeElementFound, uselessElementFound, k, pos, max, faults = 0;

    //cache initialization
    for(size_t i = 0; i < std::min((int) setupQueries.size(), nQueries); ++i){
        cache[i] = setupQueries[i];
    }

    std::cout<<"setupQueries="<<setupQueries.size()<<" nQueries="<<nQueries<<std::endl;

    for(size_t i=0; i<cacheSize; i++)
        std::cout<<"cache["<<i<<"] empty="<<cache[i].empty()<<std::endl;

    //for each query
    for(size_t i = 0; i < nQueries; ++i){
        cacheHitFound = freeElementFound = 0;

        std::cout<<"i="<<i<<std::endl;
        //if i-th query is the j-th cached element, then cache hit
        for(size_t j = 0; j < cacheSize; ++j){
            if(!cache[j].empty() && cv::norm(cache[j], queries[i]) <= threshold){
                cacheHitFound = freeElementFound = 1;
                cacheHits++;
                if(VERBOSE) std::cout<<"Cache hit with index "<<j<<std::endl;
                break;
            }
        }

        std::cout<<"cache hit done"<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"i="<<i<<std::endl;

        //if cacheHit is 0, then queries[i] is not cached...
        if(cacheHitFound == 0){
            //searching for an empty element in the cache
            for(size_t j = 0; j < cacheSize; ++j){
                //if there is an empty element, assign it
                if(cache[j].empty()){
                    if(VERBOSE) std::cout<<"Filling empty element"<<std::endl;
                    faults++;
                    cache[j] = queries[i];
                    freeElementFound = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        std::cout<<"empty element done"<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"i="<<i<<std::endl;


        //if freeElementFound, it means that the cache is full
        if(freeElementFound == 0){
            std::cout<<"i="<<i<<std::endl;

            uselessElementFound =0;

            std::cout<<"looking next use"<<std::endl;
            for(size_t j = 0; j < cacheSize; ++j){
                temp[j] = -1;

                std::cout<<"j="<<j<<std::endl;
                //look when queries[j] will be used next time
                for(k = i + 1; k < nQueries; ++k){
                    std::cout<<"looking element "<<k;
                    if(!cache[j].empty() && cv::norm(cache[j], queries[k]) <= threshold){
                        std::cout<<" distance computed";
                        temp[j] = k;
                        std::cout<<" assignment done";
                        break;
                    }
                    std::cout<<std::endl;
                }
            }
            std::cout<<"i="<<i<<std::endl;
            std::cout<<"looking useless"<<std::endl;
            //if a cached element will never be used again: replace it
            for(size_t j = 0; j < cacheSize; ++j){
                if(temp[j] == -1){
                    pos = j;
                    if(VERBOSE) std::cout<<"cache["<<j<<"] will never be used again"<<std::endl;
                    uselessElementFound = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }

            std::cout<<"i="<<i<<std::endl;

            std::cout<<"replacing"<<std::endl;
            //if we did not find an useless element, then replace the one that will not be used for longer
            if(uselessElementFound ==0){
                max = temp[0];
                pos = 0;
                for(size_t j = 1; j < cacheSize; ++j){
                    if(temp[j] > max){
                        max = temp[j];
                        pos = j;
                    }
                }
                if(VERBOSE) std::cout<<"cache["<<pos<<"] is the most useless element"<<std::endl;
            }
            std::cout<<"cloning pos="<<pos<<std::endl;
            std::cout<<"queries.size="<<queries.size()<<std::endl;
            std::cout<<"i="<<i<<std::endl;
            std::cout<<"queries["<<i<<"].rows="<<queries[i].rows<<std::endl;
            std::cout<<"queries["<<i<<"].cols="<<queries[i].cols<<std::endl;
            std::cout<<"queries.rows="<<queries[i].rows<<" cols="<<queries[i].cols<<std::endl;
            std::cout<<"cache.rows="<<cache[pos].rows<<" cols="<<cache[pos].cols<<std::endl;
            cache[pos] = queries[i];
            faults++;
            std::cout<<"replaced"<<std::endl;
        }

        if(VERBOSE) std::cout<<std::endl;
        for(size_t j = 0; j < cacheSize; ++j){
            if(cache[j].empty())
                break;
            if(VERBOSE) std::cout<<"cache["<<j<<"]= "<<cache[j]<<std::endl;
        }
        std::cout<<"cycle done"<<std::endl;
    }
    return cacheHits/(float)queries.size();
}
```

And I get a segmentation fault at:

```
            std::cout<<"queries["<<i<<"].rows="<<queries[i].rows<<std::endl;
```

By testing the value of `i`, I get a nonesense value.

**But as you can see from this code, `i` is NEVER assigned, it is written only for `for(size_t i = 0; i < nQueries; ++i)` **

I'm getting a seg fault at:

```
std::cout<<"queries["<<i<<"].rows="<<queries[i].rows<<std::endl;
```

`nQueries` is `1500` and `i=284`.

Again, I'm sorry for this, but I can't seriously figure out what to do.

Comment: What is the value of `nQueries`? And at which point did you get a "nonsense value" (which line)?

Comment: When does `i` get non sense value?Like `0,1,2,..,nqueries-1,nonsense`?

Comment: Are you overflowing the temp array? Its size is 10. If cache size is larger than that you'd start writing into other local variables

Comment: @Spads ok it seems that you were right: the segfault doesn't happen anymore, even though I wonder why it appeared at that line and not when trying to access `temp`

Comment: @justHelloWorld When try to access an out-of-bound index from a local array, you will not get a segfault unless you access storage you don't have access to (e.g. if you do `temp[8797974]` you may get a segfault). Here, the problem arise when `j = 10`, so you are "just" out-of-bound, and you are typically accessing storage you have access to (local stackframe of the function), so instead of getting a segfault, you write over other local variables.